# Propose an equivalence relation such that exactly one of its classes is finite

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Seems like I have a problem with understanding equivalence relations. I have the following task:

For the set of (a) natural numbers and (b) whole numbers, propose an equivalence relation such that exactly one of its classes is finite.

I understand that an equivalence relation involves partitioning a set into disjoint parts, but I do not understand how to construct such relations. I can (maybe) create only trivial ones. For example:

a. $$
R = \\{ (x,y) | x,y \in \{ 1,2,\ldots,k \}; x,y \in \{ k,k+1,\dots, \} \\}
$$
b. $$
R = \\{(x,y) | x,y \in \{ -k, \ldots, -1,-2,0,1,2,\ldots,k \}; x,y \in \{ k,k+1,\dots, \} \cup \{ k,k+1,\dots, \}\\}
$$

Can you suggest some algorithms to solve such puzzles?

Comment: How about the relation $a\sim b$ if $a$ and $b$ are both not equal to $1$ or are both equal to $1$?

Comment: An equivalence relationship is uniquely determined by the set of equivalence classes. Give a partition of your set $X$ into a family with the desired properties, then say $x\sim y$ if they belong in the same element of the partition. Pick, for example, any finite set $S$, then consider the partition $\{S,X\setminus S\}$. For $S=\{1\}$, you get @CharlesHudgins' example.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Thank you for your suggestion! It's indeed an equivalence relation with one finite class. But for me, it's not a problem to check formally 3 properties (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity) for a GIVEN set and relation.
I don't understand how to come up with it by myself. Is there any strategy that I can follow to create a relation that is an equivalence relation for a given arbitrary set?

Comment: @Alessandro I think I understand. Thanks a lot!